# How to delete on express without specificate the whole route

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route like this on express

```
app.delete('/items/:id', function (req,res) {
...
})
```

When I try to send a delete request on:

http://localhost/items/10 I delete the item successfully.

However, if I try to send the delete to http://localhost/items I get Cannot DELETE /items

Why can't I access to app.delete when I don't specify the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I access to app.delete when I don't specify the id?

Because if you want that, you need to tell Express that the `id` is [optional](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#optional), like this:

```
app.delete('/items/:id?', function (req,res) {
...
})
```

This will match the following requests:

- `DELETE /items/123` (where `req.params.id` will be `'123'`)
- `DELETE /items/` (where `req.params.id` will be `undefined`)
- `DELETE /items` (where `req.params.id` will also be `undefined`)

Answer (score 0):

As in express routing mechanism `request` is deals for **POST**,**GET**,**PUT**, **DELETE** ,it expects the resource in your `server`.

when you first define route

```
`http://localhost/items/10`  it matches the request with your route that expect
```

parameter then it find the resource and delete it

As compared to other `http://localhost/items` It assume different resource and not perform or hitting that resource